# WCF service with OAuth authentication

Tags: wcf, oauth

I'm planning on using WCF for an API for my applicaition. In the Web frontend of the app, I take care of the request of access tokens etc.

So I wanted to ask how I can easily have my users specify OAuth access token etc. as parameters when calling my endpoints? Without the requirement of each method to accept the parameters?

Can it be done? I'm hosting my services in IIS, maybe I can dive into the OperationContext and catch requests, verify auth headers and throw an exception of they're wrong?

Comment: A transparent implementation is described in this blog post:
http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2008/11/14/oauth-channel-for-wcf-restful-services.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the answer I gave here can help you out: [WCF authentication from html/javascript client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18465491/wcf-authentication-from-html-javascript-client/18494392#18494392)

Best regards
db